# ggplot2 in R 3.2.3: layers broken?

Tags: r, macos, plot, ggplot2

This morning I upgraded to R 3.2.3 (OSX 10.11.1). My ggplot2 scripts of the following sort have suddenly ceased to work:

```
df <- data.frame(ind = c(20,35,45,55,70), dep = c(6,17,26,37,44))
```

**syntax 1**:

```
ggplot()+ layer(data=df, mapping=aes(x=ind, y=dep), geom="point")

"Error: Attempted to create layer with no stat."
```

ggplot2 itself is not broken since

**syntax 2:**

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=ind, y=dep)) + geom_point()
```

produces the expected plot. Syntax 1 still produces the expected plot on an old machine (R 2.15.3 OSX 10.5.8). Besides, I used it only this morning prior to the R upgrade. I have deleted and reloaded R3.2.3, ggplot2 and dependents, but the problem persists. I like Syntax 1 because I like to add layers from different datasets. I would be grateful for thoughts.

Comment: Do the machines have the same version of ggplot2?

Comment: The machines do not have the same version of ggplot. It's conceivable that ggplot updated to v.2.0.0 when I upgraded the R version. Hadley writes: "Layers are now much stricter about their arguments - you will get an error if you've supplied an argument that isn't an aesthetic or a parameter. This is likely to cause some short-term pain but in the long-term it will make it much easier to spot spelling mistakes and other errors (#1293)."  I fear that I have hit the pain.

Comment: Interesting. I could not get it to work even after adding `stat="identity",position="identity"`. It died with the message `Error: is.logical(na.rm) is not TRUE`. I think it is a bug.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to use layer() anyway, you can easily add layers with different data sets using the geoms.

Comment: There is a help page for it. Should it be depreciated?

Comment: I concur with Mike Wise. And, with Joran: this still works and permits layers to be added: ggplot()+geom_point(data=df, mapping=aes(x=ind, y=dep, colour="red")). I can't evidently upvote yet, but thank you for your attention.

Comment: here is the help page for the dev version http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/index.html

Comment: This works for me: `ggplot()+ layer(data=df, mapping=aes(x=ind, y=dep), geom="point", stat = "identity", position = "identity", params = list(na.rm = FALSE))`. It seems the the point geom need `na.rm` to be defined. There is a default for this argument when you use `geom_point`, but that seems not to be the case when using `layer`. I think that this makes sense: `layer` can be used with any geom, and not all of them may have the argument `na.rm`, or the same default value.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it works fine when we apply stat="identity",position_dodge(width=3) in function layer

```
ggplot()+ layer(data=df, mapping=aes(x=ind, y=dep), geom="point",stat="identity",position_dodge(width=3))

#data

df <- data.frame(ind = c(20,35,45,55,70), dep = c(6,17,26,37,44))
```

[image]